# How to use "Models::find()" in phalcon framework?

Tags: models, phalcon

```
$submodules = Modules::find(
    array(
        'moduleid in (:mods:) and parentid = :parentid:',
        'bind' => array(
            'mods' => '1,2',
            'parentid' => 1
        ),
        'bindtype' => array(
            'mods' => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            'parentid' => Column::BIND_PARAM_INT
        )
    )
);
```

I hope the sql that is "select * from modules where moduleid in (1,2) and parentid = 1"
but result is not correct.

help plz.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping :mods: will produce '1,2' therefore: select * from modules where moduleid in ('1,2') and parentid = 1

You need to use a bound parameter for every value in the "in":

```
$submodules = Modules::find(array(
  'moduleid in (:firstMod:, :secondMod:) and parentid = :parentId:',
  'bind' => array(    
    'firstMod' => 1,
    'secondMod' => 2,
    'parentId' => 1
  )
));
```

In this case is better use the QueryBuilder

Comment: $modules = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
                                ->from('Modules')
                                ->inWhere('moduleid',[1,2])
                                ->orderBy('sortid ASC')
                                ->getQuery()
                                ->execute();
i used QueryBuilder but output 502 bad way!

Comment: inWhere('Modules.moduleid')